# My javascript crashes the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, loops, crash

Now before everyone is helpful (seriously, you guys are awesome) I am doing a coding challenge that means I can't get code from other users/people. This does not, however, extend to advice so I wanted to know why my code crashes google chrome. I <strike>don't want</strike> am not allowed any code so please just point me in the right direction. I am sorry for such an odd request but I am at my wit's end.

http://jsfiddle.net/clarinetking/c49mutqw/9/

```
    var chars;
var keyword = [];
var cipher;
var done = false;
var list1 = [];
var list2 = [];
var list3 = [];
var list4 = [];
var list5 = [];
var keylngth = 0;

$('#apnd').click(function () {
    cipher = $('#Input').val();
    chars = cipher.split('');
    $('#Output').append(chars);
});

$('#key').click(function () {
    while (done === false) {
        var letter = prompt('insert letter, xyz to close');
        keylngth++;
        if (letter == 'xyz') {
            done = true;
        } else {
            //Push letter to keyword array
            keyword.push(letter);
        }
    }
});

$('#list').click(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        var x = 1;        
        for (i = 1; i < keylngth+1; i++) {
            if (i/x === 1) {
                list1.push(chars[x]);
            }
            if (i/x === 2) {
                list1.push(chars[x]);
            }
            if (i/x === 3) {
                list1.push(chars[x]);
            }
            if (i/x === 4) {
                list1.push(chars[x]);
            }
            if (i/x === 5) {
                list1.push(chars[x]);
            }
            if (i/x === 6) {
                list1.push(chars[x]);
            }
            if (i/x === 7) {
                list1.push(chars[x]);
            }
            if (i/x === 8) {
                list1.push(chars[x]);
            }
        }
        x++;
    }
    alert(list1);
    alert(list2);
});
```

I apologize to all you coders out there that are probably *screaming* at me *USE A REPEAT LOOP!* but for the list function I see no way to. As previously mentioned, no code please unless it's pseudo code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `$('#list').click(function ())` function you are running an infinite for bucle, it's because you use the same `i` counter for the two for bucles so you javascript will run forerver and crash the browser

Comment: Ok! Thank you! I changed the second loop variable to j AND you didn't violate my no code rule! Thanks good sir/madam/alien!!